# How to create different areas of an svg image and color them

Tags: css, svg

I have this image below which is an png and I want to fill with color different areas with css. The best way to do that is with svg. But I don't know how to make these different areas separated and color them. Is there some way to convert this image to svg and and to color different areas?

[image]

These are the areas I want to color

[image]

Comment: You need to provide the SVG code. But if the areas don't exist in the SVG you will need to create them.

Comment: You can use your brain to clip (with clipPath) the  group of different  color areas