# Get an element by ID from html to js

Tags: javascript, html, image, getelementbyid

I have created a clickable area in an image and I want to get the Id of this area in Javascript so I can fill it with color. I am new in both html and js.

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById("map1");
```

```html
<img src={marina} alt="marinamap" usemap="#workmap" />
<map name="workmap">
     <area shape="rect" coords="320,220,340,210" alt=" parking" href="" id="map1"  >
</map>
```

I am getting the error :

> a constructor,method,accessor or property was expected.

Any advice?

Comment: I made an executable snippet with your code (above) and when I run it, I'm not getting this error. I didn't alter the code in any way.

Comment: are you using angular ???

Comment: I am doing this in VS code to process a Lightning Web Component in Salesforce. You think the above code successfully gets the Id of the clickable part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't look that `<area>` tag is styleble at all... if all your areas are rectangular o round(ish) you may consider using just div's or any other tags positioned absolutely over the image [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344059/2828391)... if those areas have more complex shapes you may need to use SVG instead... [svg example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419937/how-to-create-different-areas-of-an-svg-image-and-color-them)

[ORIGINAL **WRONG** ANSWER - before comment received]

Probably related to "[Can I have an onclick event on a imagemap area element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921696/can-i-have-an-onclick-event-on-a-imagemap-area-element)"

You may do what you need in the onclick event of your area like so:

```html
<area shape="rect" 
      coords="320,220,340,210" 
      alt="parking" 
      href="#map1_target" 
      id="map1"  
      onclick="event.preventDefault(); this.style.background='#a00';"
>
```

Comment: I would like to permanently colorize this part in the overlay so I don't think onclick event would do for now.